# Update static variable in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I've read through the following code for Example 7 posted on the following answer for [How do JavaScript Closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111)

```
function newClosure(someNum, someRef) {
    // Local variables that end up within closure
    var num = someNum;
    var anArray = [1,2,3];
    var ref = someRef;
    return function(x) {
        num += x;
        anArray.push(num);
        alert('num: ' + num +
            '\nanArray ' + anArray.toString() +
            '\nref.someVar ' + ref.someVar);
      }
}
obj = {someVar: 4};
fn1 = newClosure(4, obj);
fn2 = newClosure(5, obj);
fn1(1); // num: 5; anArray: 1,2,3,5; ref.someVar: 4;
fn2(1); // num: 6; anArray: 1,2,3,6; ref.someVar: 4;
obj.someVar++;
fn1(2); // num: 7; anArray: 1,2,3,5,7; ref.someVar: 5;
fn2(2); // num: 8; anArray: 1,2,3,6,8; ref.someVar: 5;
```

I used the same logic for my example

```
function increment() {
    var id = 0;
    return function(number) {
        id += number;
        alert('Unique ID: ' + id);
    }
}

six = increment();
fourteen = increment();

six(6);
fourteen(8);
```

In the example I took inspiration from,

```
fn1(2); //num 7
```

The num outputs 7 because according to my understanding, it has been set to 5 from the previous call first time around. So using the same reasoning, I expected the fourteen(8) call to return the number 14 because I believed ID would have been updated to 6 rather than stay at 0. Why is the variable not static? How would I account for it to be static?

I also tried to have the function set a parameter of number and set the ID equal to the parameter but that did not update it either.

http://jsfiddle.net/de9syawe/4/ to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newClosure`'s closure will capture the `num` initialized to `someNum` each time it is called. Thus, `f1` has its own `num`, which starts at `4`, is incremented by one to `5`, then is incremented by two to `7`. Meanwhile, `f2` has its own `num`, which starts at `5`, is incremented by one to `6`, and again by two to `8`. The interleaving of `f1` and `f2` calls might confuse you, but they are completely separate, and share no variables.

In the same vein, the closure that `increment` constructs will capture `id` at value `0`. `six` has `id` starting at `0`, incrementing by six to `6`. `fourteen` independently starts at its own `0`, and is incremented by eight to `8`.

Compare:

```
var globalCounter = 0;
function incrementWithGlobalCounter() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function(number) {
        counter += number;
        globalCounter += number;
        alert('Counter: ' + counter + '; Global Counter: ' + globalCounter);
    }
}

var one = incrementWithGlobalCounter();
var two = incrementWithGlobalCounter();

one(1); // 1, 1
one(1); // 2, 2
two(1); // 1, 3
two(2); // 3, 5
one(5); // 7, 10
```

Here, `globalCounter` is captured by the outer closure, so it is shared by all inner closures; the `counter` is captured by the inner closure and local to outer closure, so it will be independent for each inner closure.

Comment: Thank you so much @Amadan You were right, I was confused with the f1 and f2 calls. That was a silly/stupid overlook. I didn't realize by calling fourteen, I was making a different call.

But thanks for also showing me the globalCounter and making me think about the outer closure!